# xDB Replication Console unable to connect JRMP connection establishment

Tags: oracle10g, database-replication, postgresql-9.2, transactional-replication

While trying to add a Oracle publication server to xDB Replication Console (v6.1.2), the following error is obtained:

[image]

How do I fix this? Also, how can the DB name be specified while connecting as it only asks for host, port,username and password?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create a publication and subscription server. This can be created on any system which has Postgres installed. Once that is done, a publication and subscription database is added. This is the next step where database details are entered.